# Drawing the boundaries on coordinate file and classifying the points

Tags: shapefile, coordinates

I have imported the data on coordinates in Excel which are classified into 3 types: Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3. When I *Add delimited text layer*, I get the following output:

[image]

I have two basic questions:

1. How can I draw boundaries around these points?
2. How can I classify these points into Class 1, Class 2, Class 3 so that each class is distinctly represented with a different color. Right now, everything looks the same. I just need each point to be distinctly represented and not boundary around each point!

I am using QGIS 2.4

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?  Also, the two questions are quite distinct and our Q&A format works best with one question per question so would you be able to focus it on the one which is more important to you and then research/ask the other one separately, please?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have the attributes loaded into the shapefile (a field of classification - Class1, Class2 etc), you could use [categories > Unique Values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000003m000000) in the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties window.

[Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000) tool would create a bounding box around your points.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using QGIS so any input on that will be highly appreciated. Secondly, my csv file contains unique id, x, y coordinates and a variable representing class; having values 1,2 and 3. I want to know how the points will be drawn in a distinguished color based on these classes.

Comment: the classification problem is solved. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to creating a boundary is to use the [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000) tool. You probably want to choose the Convex Hull geometry type*.

Assuming you want a distinct boundary around each class, you can first use [Select by Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) (e.g., `"CLASS = 1"`) so only a subset of features is actively selected. In that case, the Minimum Bounding Geometry would draw a polygon around just the Class 1 points; repeat for Class 2 and 3.

* *requires an ArcInfo License*